# Lilypond: How to write - when the left hand should play more than the number of notes per bar as per the time signature

Tags: notation, lilypond

This is what I am aiming for:
[image: Thumb of left hand is a different voice - what I am aiming for]

How can I tell LilyPond that the `c1` in the first three measures is to be played by the thumb of the left hand in parallel with the other three notes also played by the left hand?

```
   r4 a4_3 a4 a4 | 
   r4 g4_4 g4 g4 | 
   r4 f4_5 f4 f4 | 
   c'2_1 c,2
```

Where do I put in those `c1` notes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A polyphonic passage can be coded in a number of different ways (see the documentation [here](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.21/Documentation/notation/multiple-voices#single_002dstaff-polyphony)).

For this case, I'd suggest writing it like this:

```
<< {c1^1} \\ {r4 a4_3 a4 a4}>> | 
<< {c1} \\ {r4 g4_4 g4 g4}>> | 
<< {c1} \\ {r4 f,4_5 f4 f4}>> | 
c'2 c,2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - this works fine! But there are a couple of warnings warning: maybe input should specify polyphonic voices
warning: cannot have note heads and rests together on a stem ... For the sake of completeness - could you also please give the other way of adding this polyphony?

Comment: @saraf — That's strange, I'm not getting any warning. What version of LilyPond are you using? And what does the rest of your code look like?

Comment: Put the entire file here - http://pastie.org/p/2ERJnssC75W93lHivhSa2t

Comment: Using LilyPond 2.22.1 on Windows 10

Comment: https://imgur.com/fHoTSnb

Comment: @saraf try adding \\ between the voices as my updated code shows

Comment: Yup! That did the trick :-) Tnx

Comment: What do the double backslashes stand for? OK - got it - they create temporary voices

Comment: as I understand it, the double backslashes make both voices temporary, rather than just the second voice.  But different versions handle them differently for some reason

Comment: @saraf Using << A \\ B \\ C ... >> implicitely creates new voices for each bit and applies voiceOne, voiceTwo, ... to them. So << c1 \\ { r4 a a a } >> is equivalent to << \new Voice { \voiceOne c1 } \new Voice { \voiceTwo r4 a a a } >>. As this question is a bit basic I suggest you read this part of the documentation to get a principle understanding of how polyphony works in Lilypond: http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/multiple-voices